# Creating Scroll Interaction with Shifting Containers

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, slider

I'm seeking assistance in creating a specific scrolling interaction for a webpage. Within a container, there are 5 boxes aligned at the top and 5 boxes at the bottom. When the page loads, I want to achieve the following effect: the top 5 boxes will appear with only their left halves visible, thus creating the impression of 4.5 boxes being partially displayed. Similarly, for the bottom 5 boxes, only their right halves should be visible.

As I scroll down within this container, I'd like the following behavior: the top boxes should shift to the right until all 5 boxes are fully visible, while the bottom boxes should simultaneously shift to the left to fully reveal all 5 boxes. However, once all the boxes are fully visible, I would like this interaction to be disabled. Subsequent scrolling should then trigger the page to scroll as usual.

Conversely, when scrolling up, the opposite should happen: the fully visible boxes should shift back to their initial state with the hidden halves, and the disabled interaction should be re-enabled.

I'm planning to implement this interactive scrolling effect on my webpage. Could you provide guidance or code to achieve this desired interaction?

I tried code like this :

```js
const topBoxes = document.querySelector(".top");
const bottomBoxes = document.querySelector(".bottom");

let isEventActive = true;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (!isEventActive) return;

  const scrollY = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollY >= 100) {
    isEventActive = false;
    topBoxes.style.transform = `translateX(-100px)`;
    bottomBoxes.style.transform = `translateX(100px)`;
    return;
  }

  const shiftValue = scrollY / 2;

  topBoxes.style.transform = `translateX(${shiftValue}px)`;
  bottomBoxes.style.transform = `translateX(${shiftValue}px)`;
});
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="boxes top">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes bottom">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would expect there to be some CSS that should go along with this code? At the moment, the boxes are transparent and have `0` height so there would be no visual confirmation of a solution.